# how to get the length of a JTable

Tags: java, sql

I'm working with sql and java. I created a JTable to filtrate information from database to there.
I want to get the length of that JTable (number of rows) and print that result in a JLabel.
How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow, may you please show some effor and provide code?

Answer (score 1):

It's worth reading about [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and find more sample code on it.

Sample code:

```
TableModel dataModel = new AbstractTableModel() {
    public int getRowCount() { return rowData.length; }
    ...
   // override other method as well
}
JTable table = new JTable(dataModel);
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

Simply call the [DefaultTableModel#getRowCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getRowCount--) method to get the number of rows.